SvelteKit - How to download a file from the assets?
I'm using SvelteKit and I have a file src/assets/my-file.pdf. I'm trying to make a button to download it:
<a download="my-file.pdf" target="_blank" href="assets/my-file.pdf">
    Download
</a>

But when  I click on it, it doesn't work, I get the error File wasn't available on site.
How to download a file from the assets folder?

This is the way to use the assets in SvelteKit:
<script>
    import MyFile from '$lib/assets/my-file.pdf';
</script>

<a download="my-file.pdf" target="_blank" href={MyFile}>
    Download
</a>

